# Haskell generic typeclass with list

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

I have a class defined like this, so that `foo` takes a generic type and returns an Integer:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> Integer
```

and a couple of instances defined so it will work with `Bool` and `Char` types:

```
instance Foo Bool where
  foo _ = 10

instance Foo Char where
  foo _ = 20
```

If I now want to add an instance for a list with a generic type, I would want to do something like this:

```
instance Foo [a] where
  foo (t:ts) = (foo t) + (foo ts)
```

However, this is wrong. From my current understanding, I would want to assume that Haskell infers the types and does something like this:

> foo [False,True] -> foo False + foo True -> 10 + 10 = 20

I've looked at several books and read about polymorphism and typeclasses, including Learn You a Haskell For Great Good! but still can't wrap my head around how to solve this?

Comment: Why is it wrong? You forgot the basecase.

Comment: Indeed I did. Overlooked it while I was trying to solve the main issue.

Comment: The next step is a `data AnyFoo = forall a. Foo a => AnyFoo a` and an instance for it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to say that the list must contain `Foo` values:

```
instance Foo a => Foo [a] where
  foo (h:t) = foo h + foo t
  foo [] = 0
```

You can only call `foo h` when `h` is a `Foo` instance, so you need to qualify the type class for `[a]` so that it only works for lists of `Foo` instances.

Otherwise, if, for instance, you had a `[Int]`, `foo h` would imply that you'd try to call `foo` on an `Int` value, but `foo` isn't defined for that type.

With the above implementation for `[a]` you get expected results:

```
Prelude> foo [True,False,True]
30
Prelude> foo [True,False,True,True]
40
Prelude> foo "foo"
60
```

Comment: So in a way, adding the class constraint tells it to match with the types in the Foo class, just like changing the class constraint to Eq would tell it to look for a match in the Eq type class?

Comment: @tem887 I'm not sure what you mean by *look for a match*, but if that phrase works for you... :) The way I think of it is that instead of the type `a` being entirely unconstrained, the class constraint `Foo a` states that only those `a` types that are also `Foo` instances are allowed.

Comment: A simpler definition would be `foo = sum . map foo`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the base case:

```
instance Foo a => Foo [a] where
  foo (t:ts) = foo t + foo ts
  foo [] = 0
```

Mind that the call `foo ts` does *not* mean that we call `foo` on the second element. We actually call recursively the function we define (the `foo` in boldface), and this will thus keep calling `foo` on the *elements* of the list, until the list is exhausted, in which case the base case `foo [] = 0` will be used.

So it will evaluate:

```
   foo (False : True : [])
-> foo False + foo (True : [])
-> 20 + foo (True : [])
-> 20 + foo True + foo []
-> 20 + 20 + foo []
-> 20 + 20 + 0
-> 20 + 20
-> 40
->
```

Comment: Yes, I know. ts in this case is the tail of the list, i.e. the remaining elements. I just wanted to give a simple example with few steps :-)